# Is it an extreme if the root is not defined?

Tags: functions, roots

I'm still divided how to deal with this: Is a function straight unequal to $0$ if it is not defined at this point? E.g.

Is $f'(x) = \frac{x}{2\,\left({x^2+x}\right)^{3/2}} \neq 0$ so there is no extreme?

Or do you have to proof $\quad\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}}f'(x) = 0, \quad \displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}}f''(x) = 0$ ???

Comment: What do you mean by "a function straight unequal to 0"? Are you asking if a function necessarily has an extremum at a point if it is undefined there?

Comment: $f’$ doesn’t have to be zero at a point for it be an extremum of $f$.

Comment: Supporting @Tavish take the absolute value function.

Comment: Here $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x) =\infty$, so $0$ is a global extremum since the function is strictly increasing, but it's not a local minimum.

Comment: I thought  if $f'(x) = 0$ that point is defined as extremum? In that case I was mistaking: $\lim_{x\to infty} = 0$. Either way, I doesn't seem to converge. I take that to mean it doesn't have any determinable extremum.

Comment: Even that’s not necessary. E.g. if $f(x) = 7$ then $f’(57)=0$ but that’s not an extremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac x{x+1}}$. Yes, it has an extremum (a minimum, to be more precise) at $0$, since $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ when $x>0$.

Comment: yea, I guess there is no clear answer it's about reasoning